# Highcharts yAxis labels inside plot area and left padding

Tags: highcharts

I have a column chart that has yAxis labels inside the plot area. **DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/o4abatfo/**

This is how I have set up the labels:

```
yAxis: {
  labels: {
    align: 'left',
    x: 5,
    y: -3
  }
}
```

The problem is that the leftmost column is so near the plot area edge that labels are overlapping it. Is there a way to adjust the plot area padding so that the columns would start a bit further on the right?

[image: Chart example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same thing [in the Highcharts forum](http://forum.highcharts.com/post112498.html) and got this solution as a reply from @paweł-fus:

```js
var chartExtraMargin = 30;

Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Axis.prototype, 'setAxisSize', function (p) {
  p.call(this);
  if (this.isXAxis) {
    this.left += chartExtraMargin;
    this.width -= chartExtraMargin;

    this.len = Math.max(this.horiz ? this.width : this.height, 0);
    this.pos = this.horiz ? this.left : this.top;  
  }
});
```

However, adding this made the tooltips appear in the wrong position. This was fixed by overriding the `Tooltip.prototype.getAnchor()` method and adding the extra margin in the x coordinate:

```js
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Tooltip.prototype, 'getAnchor', function(p, points, mouseEvent) {
  var anchor = p.call(this, points, mouseEvent);
  anchor[0] += chartExtraMargin;
  return anchor;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `min` value as -0.49.

http://jsfiddle.net/o4abatfo/2/

Comment: Will you please take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/o4abatfo/3/ and this: http://jsfiddle.net/o4abatfo/4/ Can you please tell us why when we use `minPadding` in another `xAxis` it works, and if used in the same `xAxis` it doesn't?

Comment: @SebastianBochan Thanks, but it only seems to work properly with certain data. If the chart is narrow and the numbers on the y-axis are big, the same overlapping occurs.

Comment: Also, this method doesn't work at all if you have numeric values on the x-axis instead of categories.

Comment: @RaeenHashemi I guess that'll have to do. Unfortunately it uses percentages and not fixed values. It still breaks if the chart gets narrow enough.

Comment: For numbers use minPadding, for categories min value.

Comment: I guess this illustrates why the labels are usually on the outside of the plot :)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

Keep the labels on the outside, and apply the `plotBackgroundColor` as the chart `backgroundColor`.

This means that the legend will be encased in the background color too, but, again, it's on option.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/o4abatfo/11/